# Displaying a hidden div with a transition on the x property

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have an image and then a banner underneath the image. When you hover over the image, I have it go up 100px on the y-axis. What I can't figure out is how to bring the banner up the y-axis with it while hovering over the image. I am not certain if it is the way I am trying to execute the hover or what.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.project-block {
  width: 33.33333333333333333333333333%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.project-block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  position: relative;
}
.project-block img:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.project-block-banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -.01;
  background: #00a16d;
}
.project-block img:hover.project-block-banner {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-block">
  <a href="projects/eslich-wrecking">
    <img src="images/work/eslich.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="project-block-banner">
      <div class="project-block-banner-container">
        <div class="project-block-banner-name">company</div>
        <div class="project-block-banner-description">htrhr ghrth ht</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: I'd prefer not to, but if I must then I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+` **[selector in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)**, also I added `transition-duration` to banner itself.

```css
.project-block {
 width: 33.33333333333333333333333333%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.project-block img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
 position: relative;
}
.project-block img:hover {
 transform: translate(0, -100px);
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100px);
 -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}
.project-block-banner {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 bottom: -.01;
 background: #00a16d;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}
.project-block img:hover + .project-block-banner {
 transform: translate(0, -100px);
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100px);
 -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-duration: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-block">
  <a href="projects/eslich-wrecking">
    <img src="images/work/eslich.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="project-block-banner">
      <div class="project-block-banner-container">
        <div class="project-block-banner-name">ESLICH WRECKING</div>
        <div class="project-block-banner-description">htrhr ghrth ht</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```